# refresh or reload datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I'm using Jquery Datatable which includes customized rendering for columns. Based on values, I've to disable certain control in it. I want to reload/refresh/rebind my jquery datatable after post. How can I do that?

```
**Controller:**

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult PostAction(MyMOdel model)
    {
         //save changes to DB
        return Json(new
        {
            Success = result,
        });
    }

 public ActionResult MyAction()
   //grab records from DB and return JSON
 }

**View:**

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostAction", "ControllerName", null,
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "update-message",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            OnSuccess = "updateSuccess"
        }, new { @id = "myForm"

 }
        ))
{
<table id="myTbl" class="display"><tr><td>col1</td></tr></table>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
        var oTable = $('#myTbl').dataTable({
                     "sAjaxSource": "/ControllerName/MyAction",
                      <!-- more config -->

    function updateSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
        //refresh datatable;

    }
</script>
```

Update:********

I found the answer:

- clear the table ( fnClearTable )
- add new data to the table ( fnAddData)
- redraw the table ( fnDraw )

Comment: Please include your code here so we can see what's going on. Do try to pare it down to just the minimal code necessary to see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ifound the answer:

```
clear the table ( fnClearTable )

add new data to the table ( fnAddData)

redraw the table ( fnDraw )
```

Answer (score 19):

First just get datatable reference, using

```
var oTable = $("#someTable").dataTable();
```

After that do whatever, you want to :

```
Clear the table : oTable.fnClearTable();

Redraw the table : oTable.fnDraw();

Add new data to the table : oTable.fnAddData();
```

Comment: Just to clarify that is var oTable = $("#someTable").dataTable(); (note the camel case for the function).

Comment: Thanks Mat. Changed it to "dataTable".

Comment: function names are now oTable.draw() etc for api v.1.10

Comment: My current version of DataTables (1.10) does now allow the use of fnClearTable(); it returns the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).fnClearTable is not a function(…)`

Comment: try $(...).DataTable(...).clear().draw() instead.
https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
// Initially
window.table = $('#TableID').dataTable({
                    ...
                });

// Later, when table needs to be refreshed
window.table.fnDestroy(); 
// depending on the version, maybe just .destroy() instead of .fnDestroy();
```

Now just do the call you did **Initially** to reinit the table:

```
window.table = $('#TableID').dataTable({
                    ...
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

You just call `.dataTable()` on the table again, without any arguments.

So if you had done something like this:

```
$('#someTable').dataTable({
    someAttribue: someValue
});
```

You can then later do this to refresh it:

```
$('#someTable').dataTable();
```

Don't call it again with the arguments; it doesn't like that.

Comment: it didn't work. am loading jquery datatable through sAjaxSource

Comment: @user1480864: then see my comment on the question; we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var oTable = $('#groups').dataTable();
oTable.fnClearTable();
oTable.fnDestroy();
groupsList();
```

Answer (score 0):

For newer Datatable Versions this will do the Job:

```
var table = $('#yourDataTable').DataTable({...});
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

In my case I just needed to redraw it. But you can also clear and add new data before you redraw.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this is not what you are looking for:

```
oTable.fnReloadAjax();
```

That worked for me. It reloads the grid using the current ajax url config.

Comment: pt runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'fnReloadAjax'