# datatables redraw or refresh table

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a table that is field from the server side.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="eStudent-data-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Religion</th>
        <th>Knowledge Level</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="studentInfo" items="${ studentInfo }">
        <c:if test="${ studentInfo.graduate eq false }">
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" class="profiler">${ studentInfo.name }</a></td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.age }</td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.gender }</td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.religion }</td>
            <td>${ studentInfo.knowledgeLevel }</td>
        </tr>
        </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I edit the values and saved it on the database through Ajax. What I want next is to redraw or refresh the table to reflect my changes. But I'm new on using DataTables. I don't know what should I do. I'm using `java` at my server side. The samples I red so far is only `PHP`. Is there a way to do this using java as server side? and also please give a clear sample. I'm quite confused with the docs. Please bear with me.

**Update:**

I'm using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#tooltips) for my design. The `<td><a href="#" class="profiler">${ studentInfo.name }</a></td>` will show the modal along with the data in a row. I'm using [`x-editable`](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) for editing the field inside the modal. The snippet below is the sample code how I edit the field

```
$(this).editable({
    pk: studentName,       // sent to the server side
    name: id,              // sent to the server side
    url: '../admin/edit_studentInfo.do',
    success: function(response, newValue) {
            // No data call back yet.. reserving for redrawing the DataTables
        console.log('test');
    }
});
```

**Another update:**

To clarify more this code `<td><a href="#" class="profiler">${ studentInfo.name }</a></td>` I'm using [Bootstrap Modal](http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/) that contains the fields that I'm editting that will reflect to the database which is the same source of data of the DataTables. Here is the snippet to show the modal.

```
$('.profiler').on( 'click', function() {
    ... // some code to fill the field in the modal
    $modal.modal(); // show modal to the view
});
```

Comment: server language is irrelevant, the only thing browser knows is the data provided. Not clear how you are `editing values` You can directly modify the data stored by plugin for each row using plugin API. Need to see more javascript code and a bit better explanation of workflow

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for your quick response. I updated my question. You can assume that I'm using a simple ajax to edit the fields in the table but I posted a more detail in my question in case that you want the details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785494/refresh-or-realod-datatable

Comment: OK...you shouldn't have to reload, rather you want to update data for that row through the API. Look at example for `jEditable` plugin. http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/editable.html  Can help integrate the `x-editable` but need to see more code to know what `this` is

Comment: @Nouphal.M how do I exactly add the data to the table? and in what format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846999/add-update-and-delete-records-of-database-using-jquery-datatables                                        http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/7893/add-a-new-row-in-mysql-database/p1

Comment: Please give me hours to process all the links you gave me. I'll come back here for any changes.