# Using jQuery DataTables with vuejs

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, vue.js

**My Scenario:**
Hey im sustaining a system that retrieves data from a database and and then passes that data to *vue.js* with in turn displays it in *jQuery DataTabes*.

The problem i have is that when *DataTables* is originally initialized it seems the data is saved in the table i initialized.
When i retrieve new information it doesn't update the existing data and it breaks the table.

also the data coming back from the request is exactly what i need its just the *DataTables* that's giving me a problem

**What I've Tried:**

destroying the table using `$('#table').DataTable.destroy()` and then re-initializing it: either says cannot re-initialize datatables or just displays old data as usual.

Re-initializing the table with a new ID and changing the current table id to math the new ID: just doesn't work displays the table as a normal table not a datatable.

**My Question:**

How do i use *DataTables* with *vuejs* to pull ***NEW*** data without refreshing the page?

or

How to i remove and re-initialize datatables?

**Edit**: if there are any other plugins like *DataTables* then i'd love to know about them.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/gurghet/vue-smart-table

Comment: @gurghet thanks for the reccomendation! but one **vital** feat that is required in the table is that it has to be sortable. Im not very good with vue.js and dont know how to use most of the components used in this table.

Comment: it *is* sortable, I'm sorry it's not clear from the readme. in particular is sortable numerically, lexicographically and with custom functions. About the components, you don't need them, they are optional.

Comment: Just use the redraw function of data tables  inside a watch or computed property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785494/refresh-or-reload-datatable

Comment: Here is the official doc for the draw function https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: Please see my linked answer to a similar question, and see if it solves your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755853/implementing-vue-js-datatables-properly/36039381#36039381

Answer (score 0):

> How do i use DataTables with vuejs to pull NEW data without refreshing
>   the page?

**Let Datatable do this job** and use its server-side processing feature:
https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

If you're using **Vue 1.x** and you want your **action buttons** works e.g.: you're returning an html  with uncompiled vue directives in your json - you can just recompile the datatables wrapper everytime you fetch new data:

```
$('#datatable').dataTable({
   ...
    drawCallback: function (settings) {
        var $element = $('#datatable');
        vm.$compile($element.get(0)); // vm refers to Vue instance
    },
 ...
});
```

Note: **$compile** has been removed in **Vue 2.x**

Comment: What's an alternative for v2?

Answer (score 0):

For client-side data, you can probably do something like this:

```
dataTable.clear().draw();
dataTable.rows.add(newDataArray).draw();
```

(Shameless Plug) I also wrote a wrapper plugin that may help integrate directly with server-side: https://github.com/niiknow/vue-datatables-net

MIT so you are free to use it as you wish or browse through the code to get an idea of how to use jQuery DataTables with Vue.