# jquery datatables remove row by index

Tags: jquery, datatables

I know this question is popular but all answers are for selected rows.  I am trying to delete / remove a row that is NOT selected.  I have a variable for the table that I want to remove the row from and I have the index of the row that I want to remove.

These are various ways to get a handle to the table or rows:

```
var table = $('#tableName');
var rows = $('#tableName tbody tr').toArray();
var oTable = $('#tableName').dataTable();
```

I know how to use the `row.remove()` method on a selected row.

```
var jThisButton = $(this);
var jRow = jThisButton.parents("tr");
jRow.remove();
```

**But my row is NOT selected**; instead I have an index.  Let's say my index is 2. Using something like the above code, perhaps I can get row by index and remove it like this:

```
var jRow = table.find('tr').eq(index);
jRow.remove();
```

**Except that does not work**.  That code moves the row I want to delete to the last row and goes wonky, showing the search bar.

[image]

You can see in the image below that I have 4 rows in the table.

**How do I remove the tr that exists at index 2?**

[image]

I have not been able to find the answer to this question anywhere.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[fnDeleteRow](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnDeleteRow) is the correct function to use, but it's not as straight-forward as you'd think:

```
$('#delete').click(function(e){
    var row = oTable.find('tr').eq(3);
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(row[0]);
})
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/markps/yzskm2ny/6/) for a working version.

Comment: That does delete the row but, in the process of removing the row, the search bar and the bottom section that shows the number of entries (I don't know what you call the header and footer of the dataTable) gets displayed.  So now that I can delete the row, how do I hide that from the view?  Maybe I should ask a new question.

Comment: I'm guessing the reason those controls are showing is that you've hidden them using jquery on page load, rather than useing the API?

Comment: Yes.  Is there any remedy?  I've been working this from two different angles.  Trying to delete a row and also building a new array to clear and reload the table.  Who'da thought this would be so difficult?  :-(

Comment: Use the [sDom](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/options#sDom) option in the datatables initialisation to specify which datatable elements you want to display, so if you want to hide the filter input and pagination controls - `"sDom" : "ltr"`.  If you post your datatables initialisation code I can amend it to suit.

Comment: I will post as soon as I can.  Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```
oTable.row(index).remove().draw();
```

Removing the tr from the DOM will not remove it from DataTable.
If the DataTable is drawn once again, the deleted rows will return to view.

The `remove()` will remove the row from DataTable and calling `draw()` will update the DataTable. This will also update the row count information.

**UPDATE**

For DataTable 1.9.4 the below code will work

`oTable.fnDeleteRow(index);`

`draw()` is not required as the DataTable is refreshed after `fnDeleteRow()`

Comment: I'm using a legacy version of dataTable.  I tried .draw() before and it was not recognized as a function.  I tried it again using your code and I get the same error on oTable.row is not a function.

Comment: I looked for legacy draw() method and found .fnDraw() in this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/14943639/1735836, which refreshed the table with the row added back in.

Comment: Could you please specify the version of DT you use?

Comment: DataTables-1.9.4

Comment: That worked just like Sushant's answer but the table is still displayed like the image in my question.  How can I get the table to display correctly?

Comment: fnDeleteRow is not a function

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
$("tr").eq(1).remove();
```

Comment: That removed the row, but it's still wonky with the Search bar showing and at the bottom of the table it still shows 'Showing 1 to 4 of 4 entries' even though there are only 3 rows now.

Comment: For the second part :
   var rowCount = $('#tablename tr').length;

it will fetch you the active entries.

Comment: I don't want to see the active entries.  How do I make the table display correctly?